# What is Danny Kaye saying in his three-language blurb in The Court Jester?

Tags: dialogue

In the embedded scene in [The Court Jester](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0049096/) with Danny Kaye, he rattles off lengthy blurbs in French, Italian, and German. It's quite entertaining, but I've always wanted to know what the English translation is of those 3 blurbs.

Anybody know? There must be people that speak French, Italian, or German here on Stack, that could answer. :-)

Comment: I know enough French and Italian to be convinced that he is not saying anything coherent. To me, that makes it funnier, because all he is apparently doing is mimicking the accents with added body gestures.

Answer (score 2):

Danny Kaye was famous for his gibberish routines in various languages. These are all nonsense, and vintage Kaye.

Comment: they definitely contain some real words. In the French I spotted fleur several times, along with romantique.

Answer (score 1):

German:

Was (What) haben (have) Sie (you) ausgehelden (gibberish) das (the)
kneipende (gibberish) haben (have)? Das (The) Schmerzen (pain) hölewiedie (gibberish) kneipende (gibberish) höben (gibberish). Haben (Have) sie (sie)
geflunden (gibberish) didöhaih haiben se geflunden des (complete gibberish) Weiße (white) geknäu schnetzen etc. (complete gibberish from now on).

It really sounds like German and me and my girlfriend ended laughing hysterically.

Comment: Thorsten, that is wonderful. I can't help wondering what it would sound like if a non-English-speaking person were to construct a long string of sounds that was intended to sound "English"--and may in fact sound like he was speaking English, to someone who actually didn't understand English. I would laugh my head off. (Anybody want to give it a try??)

Comment: @HerrimanCoder I'll try (German native speaker): `What is you tinking and the brun? Hold the snart over the bee and be rubble before mine. Not neever shrub, is it, no whaggerishly empartimention under. Geely meany buster shoe`

Comment: Nice! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vt4Dfa4fOEY